# acts_as_api and bullet N+1 queries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-bullet

I am using `acts_as_api` to provide a JSON response for some models in my system. My API related code is (reduced to make the example easier):

```
# File app/modes/item.rb

# API
acts_as_api

api_accessible :v1_list do |template|
  template.add :id
  template.add :client_name
end
```

This API is working as expected. It is important to know that `client_name` is a method containing:

```
def client_name
    client.name
end
```

That is, the client name is not included in the item model but in the client model. Thus, this info is not contained in the items table.

Using [Bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) gem I have noticed that a N+1 query is being performed in the clients table. For each item, a SQL query to the clients table is also performed.

I know that ActiveRecord has some utilities in the API that avoids N+1 queries, and I would like to know if there is a way to use that ActiveRecord feature together with `acts_as_api` gem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gem [documentation](http://fabrik42.github.io/acts_as_api/) shows this

```
def index
  @users = User.all

  #Note that it’s wise to add a root param when rendering lists.

  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml  { render_for_api :name_only, :xml => @users, :root => :users  }
    format.json { render_for_api :name_only, :json => @users, :root => :users }
  end
end
```

So for your case you should simply eager load the client association

```
def index
  @items = Item.includes(:client).all

  # Note that it’s wise to add a root param when rendering lists.

  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml  { render_for_api :name_only, :xml => @items, :root => :items  }
    format.json { render_for_api :name_only, :json => @items, :root => :items }
  end
end
```

Comment: This is correct! acts_as_api does not interfere with the best practices of AR preloading like includes/preload. If you preload your AR associations correctly, it will not cause additional queries.